# Calling pre-defined code from within a Ruby block

Tags: ruby, yield, prawn

I'm trying to do a highly formatted document using PrawnPDF, and would like a way to call a function to produce a particular piece of text over and over but in different places. What I have is this

```
@pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:margin => [5, 5], :page_size => 'A4') do
    text
    text
    <insert general text>
    text
    text
    <insert general text>
    etc etc
end

pdf.generate("output.pdf")
```

The general text i want to insert is this:

```
pdf.bounding_box([column_check,pdf.cursor], :width => 250, :height => 12) do
    pdf.stroke_color "894131"
    pdf.stroke do
        pdf.fill_color "894131"
        pdf.fill_and_stroke_rounded_rectangle [pdf.cursor - 12,pdf.cursor], 288, 12, 0
        pdf.fill_color 'FFFFFF'
    end

    pdf.pad(5) do
        pdf.draw_text(prices[:manganese], :at => [4, pdf.cursor - 4], :size => 6)
    end
    pdf.fill_color '000000'
end 
pdf.move_down 2
```

(i've changed the way I've generated the pdf to be implicit)

It doesn't look like I can call a function from within the Prawn::Document.new block, how can I get around this? I don't know all that much programming, so I feel there is a solution using a yield block, or a proc, or something I don't have much experience with...

(basically each time I call this I want to be able to call a different symbol for the prices hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's required to access a method outside the scope of the block, I'd use the `generate()` with explicit block form:

```
def general_text(pdf)
  pdf.bounding_box(...) do
    # ...
  end
  pdf.move_down 2
end

@pdf = Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf", {:margin => [5, 5], :page_size => 'A4'}) do |pdf|
    pdf.text
    pdf.text
    general_text(pdf)
    pdf.text
    pdf.text
    general_text(pdf)
    # ...
end
```

Didn't check it myself, but think should work.

**UPDATE**
To use different keys for hash, add another argument to general_text() method:

```
def general_text(pdf, key)  
  # ... prices[key] ...
end

@pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(...) do |pdf|
  ...
  general_text(pdf, :manganese)
  ...
end
```